# Date/Time Addition/Subtraction in Python

Tags: python-3.x

My code is now:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date_format = "%d/%m/%Y %H%M%S"
a = datetime.strptime('19/11/2014 090000', date_format)
b = datetime.strptime('25/11/2014 114736', date_format)
delta = b - a
del_sec = delta.seconds
minutes = del_sec//60
hours = minutes//60
print (delta.days,"day(s) " "%02d:%02d:%02d" " HH:MM:SS"% (hours, minutes % 60, del_sec % 60 ))
```

Which is able to include days also; I want a variable 'c' to store the current time and subtract 'a' from 'c' in the existing format.

I tried different combinations but they are not working.

Comment: You want c to store the current "time" or the current "date and time" ?

Comment: current date and time so that I can add and subtract after few days or on the same day.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a datetime with strptime it has no timezone information. This is also true if you get the current UTC time with datetime.utcnow() or the current datetime for your machine's timezone with datetime.now().

Not sure what you are looking for. Probably not this, but maybe you can say why it is not what you want:

```
b = datetime.strptime('25/11/2014 054736', date_format)
c = datetime.now()
print(b)
print(c)
print(c - b)
```

> 2014-11-25 05:47:36
> 2014-11-25 06:08:41.797725
>
> 0:21:05.797725

Comment: Partially, I am in UTC+5:30 Zone; how to add this offset. If that can be done then this is exactly what I want.

Comment: Exactly! this is what I want. I don't know why I missed this.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice for most of the Date/Time requirements:

```
//Code tested on Python 3.4 Windows 10 and Android libpython2.6 Android

//Include the following two lines if you want to run the code on Android
//import android
//droid = android.Android()

from datetime import datetime

date_format = "%d/%m/%Y %H%M%S"     // Used for a and b

a = datetime.strptime('23/11/2014 093000', date_format)
b = datetime.strptime('24/11/2014 093000', date_format)
c = datetime.now()
d= datetime.strptime('093000', '%H%M%S')        // Only for time comparison if someone need it.
e= datetime.strptime('093000', '%H%M%S')

delta = c - b                       // Difference between time(s); you can play with a,b and c here since they are in same format

gr=d==e                         // Comparison operator on time if needed can use (>, <, >=, <= and == etc.); time only
print(gr)

fr=c>=b                         // Comparison operator on time if needed can use (>, <, >=, <= and == etc.); date and time                  
print(fr)

days = delta.days

del_sec = delta.seconds
fsec = del_sec%60

minutes = del_sec//60
fmin = minutes%60

fhour = minutes//60

print("%02d:Day(s) %02d:Hour(s) %02d:Minute(s) %02d:Second(s)" %(days,fhour,fmin,fsec))
```